# Unauthorized on Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cursor, roles, feathersjs

What role should I need add to the user to solve the problem below?

```
Unauthorized: not authorized on backend to execute command { aggregate: "activities", pipeline: [ { $indexStats: {} }, { $project: { name: 1, usageHost: "$host", usageCount: "$accesses.ops", usageSince: "$accesses.since" } } ], cursor: {} }
```

I'm creating a user using the [following script](https://github.com/vepo/mongo/blob/master/configure-mongo.sh):

```
use $APPLICATION_DATABASE
db.createUser({user: '$APPLICATION_USER', pwd: '$APPLICATION_PASS', roles:[{role:'readWrite', db:'$APPLICATION_DATABASE'}]})
```

But when I try to integrate using [feathers-sync](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-sync) the error above is throwed.

Comment: Is mongod started with authentication enabled?

Comment: Yes! I changed to dbAdmin and works, but I believe it is not the best solution

Comment: I hope my answer helps you

Comment: I will check soon! :)

Comment: Create the user in Admin db, `use admin  db.createUser({user: '$APPLICATION_USER', pwd: '$APPLICATION_PASS'})` then `use $APPLICATION_DATABASE db.grantRolesToUser("username", ["readWrite"])`

Comment: The readWrite role should work fine. Can you check whether the user actually got created correctly, with the role (and database) the way you intended?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could grant:

```
clusterMonitor
```

Which would provide the user with read-only access to monitoring tools, such as;

```
dbStats
indexStats
```

Or you could create a custom role and limit the action to a single collection:

```
use admin
db.createRole(
   {
   role: "CustomIndexStat",
   privileges: [
    { resource: { db: "", collection: "" }, 
      actions: [ "indexStats"] 
    } ],
     roles: []
   }
)
```